# Why am I getting "Call to undefined function get_filenames()"?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to get a list of file names using the [url helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/file_helper.html) but I'm getting the following error:

> Call to undefined function get_filenames()

I auto-loaded the url helper and then explicitly loaded it in the Controller and I still get the error. Why am I getting this error?

Controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Downloads extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {   
        $this->load->helper("url");
        $this->template->write_view('content', 'download_view');
        $this->template->render();
    }
}
```

View:

```
<? get_filenames("/somefolder"); ?>
```

Comment: it should be file helper

Comment: That was so stupid of me. Woops. Thank you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have loaded the [url helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) which does not contain anything similar to `get_filenames()`.
Maybe you meant to load the [file helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/file_helper.html) instead:

```
$this->load->helper('file');
```

Comment: Bit of a senior moment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a function named `get_filenames()` defined. May be need to include the file correctly. Trying using `$this` with the name.